# Insert into temporary table while statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i <= 11
BEGIN
DECLARE @YEAR nvarchar(4) = 2021
DECLARE @date DATETIME = dateadd(month, @i, @YEAR );
WITH BSQuery 
AS 
( SELECT  aCCOUNT, [GroupMask], T2.FormatCode, T2.[AcctName], (select month(@date))[month],
( CASE WHEN T2.GroupMask in (2, 3) 
Then -(Sum(T1.[Debit]-T1.[Credit])) ELSE Sum(T1.[Debit]-T1.[Credit]) END) [Balance] FROM OJDT T0 INNER JOIN JDT1 T1 
ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId] INNER JOIN OACT T2 ON T1.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode] WHERE T2.[GroupMask] in (1,2,3) 
and (T0.[RefDate]) <= EOMONTH(@date) GROUP by  T2.FormatCode,T2.[AcctName] ,
[GroupMask],aCCOUNT) Select * from BSQuery Order By 1,2
SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

The above is my SQL query, i need to insert into the temp table. how do i modify this?

Comment: You should format your query to be more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like mixing imperative and declarative languages.

How about that declaring the twelve months numbers beforehand and using a CROSS JOIN?

```
DECLARE @YEAR nvarchar(4) = 2021;

WITH Months(monthNumber) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT monthNumber + 1 FROM T WHERE monthNumber < 12)
SELECT
  aCCOUNT,
  [GroupMask],
  T2.FormatCode,
  T2.[AcctName],
  monthNumber [month],
  IIF(T2.GroupMask IN (2, 3), -1, 1) * SUM(T1.[Debit] - T1.[Credit]) [Balance]
FROM Months
CROSS JOIN OJDT T0
INNER JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId]
INNER JOIN OACT T2 ON T1.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode]
WHERE T2.[GroupMask] IN (1,2,3) 
  AND T0.[RefDate] <= EOMONTH(@YEAR, monthNumber - 1)
GROUP by monthNumber, T2.FormatCode, T2.[AcctName], [GroupMask], aCCOUNT
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Please note that it's hard to work without sample schema/data.

Comment: i have created an temporary table as T and added the monthnumber from 1 to 12. I am getting error

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: We are here to help, not to do your job for you. If you are playing with this kind of query you are supposed to have a minimum understanding of what is going on ... In this case there is a missing semicolon after the DECLARE. I updated the query accordingly.

Also, please help us to help you. I created this query without having a description of your schema or sample data. So I was not able to test my query. There may be other mistakes in the query.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really missed out the semi colon. The query is working faster than while loop.. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that it helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a temp table and then use the insert table before the select statement.

```
create table #temp(
aCCOUNT varchar(255),
groupmask varchar(255),
formatcode varchar(255),
acctname varchar(255),
month int,
Balance bigint
)
DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i <= 11
BEGIN
DECLARE @YEAR nvarchar(4) = 2021
DECLARE @date DATETIME = dateadd(month, @i, @YEAR );
WITH BSQuery 
AS 
( SELECT  aCCOUNT
, [GroupMask]
, T2.FormatCode
, T2.[AcctName]
,(select month(@date))[month]
,( CASE WHEN T2.GroupMask in (2, 3)  Then -(Sum(T1.[Debit]-T1.[Credit])) ELSE Sum(T1.[Debit]-T1.[Credit]) END) [Balance] 
FROM OJDT T0 
INNER JOIN JDT1 T1 
ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId] 
INNER JOIN OACT T2 
ON T1.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode] 
WHERE T2.[GroupMask] in (1,2,3) 
and (T0.[RefDate]) <= EOMONTH(@date) 
GROUP by  T2.FormatCode,T2.[AcctName] ,[GroupMask],aCCOUNT
) insert into #temp (account,groupmask,formatcode,acctname,month,balance)
Select account,groupmask,formatcode,acctname,month,balance from BSQuery Order By 1,2
SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: i cannot able to see the results, its just showing like this  Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(87 rows affected)
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(87 rows affected)
Warning: Null value

Comment: this is just a warning in aggregate operation. you need to run `select * from #temp` to retrieve the rows that are loaded

Comment: did it work? is this what you expected